# css resizing image as parent div shrinks

Tags: html, css, image

Whenever I vertically resize the webpage, the image will not stick within its parent container(banner) and instead overflows once the parent div is smaller than the image dimensions. This can be seen in the code snippet by viewing the borders of both the container and image as you vertically resize. Any way I can have the image shrink once the parent div becomes smaller than the image?

```css
/* Styling used for index pages including registration form and reset password pages. */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100vw; /* 100% of the viewport width */
  height: 100vh; /* 100% of the viewport height */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  background: #595959;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #FFD700;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.banner{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.banner img{
  height: auto;
  border: 3px solid red;
 }
 
 main{
  display: flex;
  flex: 4;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <header>
   <div class="banner">  
    <h1>Quiz Manager</h1>
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x115" alt="Logo">
   </div>
  </header>
  <main>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="form-container">
     <form action="index.php" method="POST">
      <div class="form-row">
       <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['username']) ?  htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']) : '' ?>" placeholder="Username">
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
       <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
       <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
      </div>
     </form>
     </div>
     <div class="links">
      <a href="forgot-password/forgotPass.php" id="forgotPass">Forgot Password?</a> 
     <p id="or">or</p>
     <!--If user needs to register an account, they can follow this link.-->
     <a href="signup.php" id="Signup">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </main>
 </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you sure you only want to resize the image? That is not very effective, since the banner text will keep its size, so it will overflow as well.

Comment: looking at it now, the h1 tag needs to resize as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the image, you can use a `max-height` in `vh`. I used `70vh`, but you can adjust this to your needs.
For the text size, there is no `max-font-size`, so I did this using a media query.

```css
/* Styling used for index pages including registration form and reset password pages. */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  font-family: 'Lato', 'Arial', sans-serif;
  width: 100vw;  /* 100% of the viewport width */
  height: 100vh; /* 100% of the viewport height */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  background: #595959;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #FFD700;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.banner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.banner img {
  height: auto;
  border: 3px solid red;
  max-height: 70vh;  /* adjust image to small screens */
}

main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 4;
}

@media (max-height: 15rem) { /* adjust font size to small screens */
  header {font-size:16.67vh;}
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <header>
      <div class="banner">
        <h1>Quiz Manager</h1>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x115" alt="Logo">
      </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <div class="container">
        <div class="form-container">
          <form action="index.php" method="POST">
            <div class="form-row">
              <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['username']) ?  htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']) : '' ?>" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
              <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
              <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
        <div class="links">
          <a href="forgot-password/forgotPass.php" id="forgotPass">Forgot Password?</a>
          <p id="or">or</p>
          <!--If user needs to register an account, they can follow this link.-->
          <a href="signup.php" id="Signup">Sign Up</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap the image in a div and then set both the wrapping div and img to `height: 100%` it should do the trick.

See snippet:

```css
/* Styling used for index pages including registration form and reset password pages. */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  font-family: 'Lato', Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100vw; /* 100% of the viewport width */
  height: 100vh; /* 100% of the viewport height */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

header {
  background: #595959;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #FFD700;
  font-size: 2.5em;
}

.banner{
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px solid red;
}

.img-wrap {
height: 100%;
text-align: right;
}

.banner img{
  border: 3px solid red;
  height: 100%
 }
 
 main{
  display: flex;
  flex: 4;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <div class="wrapper">
  <header>
   <div class="banner">  
    <h1>Quiz Manager</h1>
        <div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/115x115" alt="Logo">
        </div>
   </div>
  </header>
  <main>
   <div class="container">
    <div class="form-container">
     <form action="index.php" method="POST">
      <div class="form-row">
       <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['username']) ?  htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']) : '' ?>" placeholder="Username">
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
       <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
       <button type="submit" name="submit">Login</button>
      </div>
     </form>
     </div>
     <div class="links">
      <a href="forgot-password/forgotPass.php" id="forgotPass">Forgot Password?</a> 
     <p id="or">or</p>
     <!--If user needs to register an account, they can follow this link.-->
     <a href="signup.php" id="Signup">Sign Up</a>
    </div>
   </div>
  </main>
 </div>
</body>
```